# Why BasicResponseHandler doesn't consume response entity after successfully get the response string

Tags: httpclient, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x

I face a `ConnectionPoolTimeOutException` recently, and I am wondering if it relates to my response handler. If response entity is resource and should be freed as soon as it is not needed, why the Apache `BasicResponseHandler` does not consume entity before return response string?

```
@Immutable
public class BasicResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<String> {

    /**
     * Returns the response body as a String if the response was successful (a
     * 2xx status code). If no response body exists, this returns null. If the
     * response was unsuccessful (>= 300 status code), throws an
     * {@link HttpResponseException}.
     */
    public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response)
            throws HttpResponseException, IOException {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(),
                    statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }

        //Why not this:
        //EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        //String responseStr = entity == null ? null : EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        //return responseStr;

        return entity == null ? null : EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is taken care of by [CloseableHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html#220)

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicResponseHandler: 
    if status is greater than 300
        invokes EntityUtils.consume(); 
    else 
        invokes EntityUtils.toString();
```

If you look at those two methods, both of them closes the Inputstream as shown below.

```
public final class EntityUtils {

    public static void consume(HttpEntity entity) throws IOException {
        // ..
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        // ..
        instream.close();
        //..
    }

    public static String toString(HttpEntity entity, String defaultCharset) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // ..
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        // ..    
        instream.close();

        return var9;
    }
}
```